# Find the vector v that has norm equal to 3 and has the same direction as the vector <0,1,-1>

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What I did was normalized v, which gives $v=\sqrt{0^{2}+1^{2}+-1^{2}}$ then I divided that by the norm of the vector with the same direction so that $u=\sqrt{2}/3$ and multiply that by vector v's coordinates. Is there something I'm missing? I got only partial credit on this one.

Comment: I don't see an answer to the question here.  Your expression $v=\sqrt {0^2+1^2+(-1)^2}$ defines a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: So what did you get as a result? Your description sounds like you may have produced $\langle 0,\frac{\sqrt 2}3,-\frac{\sqrt 2}3\rangle$ rather than the correct $\langle 0,\frac3{\sqrt 2},-\frac3{\sqrt 2}\rangle$.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}/3<0,1,-1>$ was my answer

Comment: Could you elaborate on why my answer is wrong, Henning Makholm?

Comment: Compute the norm of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

actually,you have to multiply 3/√2 with the vector coordinates.we know that the vector is parallel to <0,1,-1>.so,let it be <0,k,-k>.now,we also now that the modulus of the vector is 3.so,√(k^2+k^2)=3.this implies that k=3/√2.therefore,the vector is <0,3/√2,-3/√2>.